# How to make grow work with forest?

Tags: forest

I'm trying to get this example from pg 42 of the the forest documentation to work:

```
\begin{forest}
delay={where in content={grow}{
for current/.pgfmath=content,
content=\texttt{#1}
}{}
}
[{grow=south}
[{grow’=west}[1][2][3]
[{grow’’=90}[1][2][3]]]
[2][3][4]
[{grow=east}[1][2][3]
[{grow’’=90}[1][2][3]]]]
\end{forest}
```

But the grow parameter is not accepted; with various combinations of packages loaded, I get the error:

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/grow^^92', to which you p
assed 'west', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have typographic curly quotes `grow’` but you need ascii straight apostrophe `grow'`

Comment: Rather treacherous documentation, since the example was copy-pasted from there!

Now to figure out  how to get my own much simpler example to work (I don't think the control of direction is very well documented).

Comment: @AveryAndrews You could report that [here](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest/issues) although in general getting pretty-printed code in pdf  that cuts and pastes as plain acii code is harder than one would hope.